# Is this a correct way to use property in python

Tags: python, getter-setter

Please check the following sample code, I'm wondering if version 1 is a correct way to use `property` in python. Or should I follow version 2 pattern? Or none of them is correct?

```
class Queue():
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = []

    def add(self, val):
        self._queue.append(val)

    def pop(self):
        return self._queue.pop(0)

# version 1
class Peer():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self._job_queue = Queue()

    @property
    def job_queue(self):
        return self._job_queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    peer = Peer('195.12.3.4', '8888')
    peer.job_queue.add('some stuff')
    peer.job_queue.pop()

# version 2
class Peer():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self._job_queue = Queue()

    def add_to_queue(self, val):
        self._job_queue.add(val)

    def pop_from_queue(self):
        return self._job_queue.pop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    peer = Peer('195.12.3.4', '8888')
    peer.add_to_queue('some stuff')
    peer.pop_from_queue()
```

Comment: Why not just make `job_queue` a public attribute?  What is the advantage of having a private `_job_queue` and a public `@property` (`job_queue`) that simply returns the private version?

Comment: if you are not doing any special processing with the property you should just use the attribute instead.

Comment: @mgilson perhaps the OP wants to prevent somebody from setting the value on the attribute?

Comment: @mgilson I thought it would be a good practice to protect private attributes, like in java?

Comment: @EliKorvigo -- Yeah, the only thing the property buys you is the ability to discourage users from setting a different `Queue` as `Peer.job_queue`.  I would again ask _why_ that is helpful.  There may be legitimate reasons to prevent that, but most of the time, if a user _is_ trying to do that, they probably have a legitimate reason be trying that too (and if it breaks, hey -- it's their fault)

Comment: @shangsunset -- Protecting private things is good, but only if they're actually meant to be private.  Having a private attribute with an interface that simply exposes it publicly is needless complexity.

Comment: python IS NOT java.  Different mindset.  Don't write python code using java mindset.  Unless you need to restrict or modify what job_queue can be, just use an attribute.